# Many windows appears of click on Button ADD -MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have Button ADD. When I click on it, I have a new window. I add the new Customer, my datagrid refreshes but just the first time! 
Then every time I click on Button Add, I have a new window with the same information and so on... I get many windows ADD!

ViewModel:

```
        private ObservableCollection<Custmor> _loadDataBinding;    
    public ObservableCollection<Custmor> loadDataBinding
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadDataBinding;
        }
        set
        {
            _loadDataBinding = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("loadDataBinding");
        }
    }


     public ViewModel1()
    {
             //Display my DataGrid 
        using (Test1Entities context = new Test1Entities())
        {
            _loadDataBinding = new ObservableCollection<Custmor>(context.Custmor.ToList());
        }

        //To Show the Window ADD from Window MainWindow
        addCustomerMainWindow = new RelayCommand(add, canexecute);          


        CustomerToAddObject = new Custmor();


        addCustomer1 = new RelayCommand(ADDFunction);       
    }   



    //To Show the Window ADD from Window MainWindow
    private ICommand addCustomerMainWindow;
    public ICommand AddCustomerMainWindow
    {
        get { return addCustomerMainWindow; }
    }

    private void add(object obj)
    {          
        Add addView = new Add();           
        addView.DataContext = this;
        addView.Show();      
    }

    //The Button ADD from Window ADD
    private ICommand addCustomer1;
    public ICommand AddCustomer1
    {
        get { return addCustomer1; }
    }

    private void ADDFunction(object obj)
    {
        using (Test1Entities context = new Test1Entities())
        {
            context.Custmor.Add(customerToAddObject);
            context.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Customer a été ajouté avec succès!");                
        }         

        _loadDataBinding.Add(CustomerToAddObject);
    }       



   //textBox for window ADD: CustomerToAddObject.nom ;CustomerToAddObject.prenom and CustomerToAddObject.reference
  private Custmor customerToAddObject;

    public Custmor CustomerToAddObject
    {
        get { return customerToAddObject; }
        set { customerToAddObject = value; }
    }
```

How can I fix it for when I ADD a customer, the window ADD closes, and the Mainwindow still updates and so on? Clicking on the button ADD and it adds new customers, as many times as I want?

The result of my error:
[image]

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a reference to the Add window and close it using this one. Something like this:

```
private Add addView;
private void add(object obj)

    if (addView != null)
        addView.Close();

    addView = new Add();
    addView.DataContext = this;
    addView.Show();
}

private void ADDFunction(object obj)
{
    using (Test1Entities context = new Test1Entities())
    {
        context.Custmor.Add(customerToAddObject);
        context.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Customer a été ajouté avec succès!");
    }

    _loadDataBinding.Add(CustomerToAddObject);

    if (addView != null)
        addView.Close();
    CustomerToAddObject = new Custmor();
}
```

Comment: You are Genius!!
Thanks a lot!!
It is correct..thank you very much